# Twilio: How do I enable Alpha SMS Sender IDs?

Tags: twilio

The Twilio [docs](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181348-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-for-Twilio-Programmable-SMS) says

> Please note the Alpha Numeric Sender Ids will be auto-enabled once you upgrade the account.

That's nice, but how do I upgrade the account? The account is already a paid account with a positive balance.

Answer (score 1):

Alphanumeric Sender ID is only available in specific countries that support it. Did you check the list and see if the country your are sending to supports it?

Your account is [upgraded](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183208-Upgrading-to-a-paid-Twilio-Account) if you associated a credit card with it.

[International support for Alphanumeric Sender ID](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID)